# Why when SendAndClose is being called, stream does not return io.EOF error

Tags: grpc, http2, grpc-go

I was trying to simulate a client/server gRPC using client streaming to test SendAndClose called from the server.
The test runs a client that sends a request every 7 seconds and a server that  receives the request and call SendAndClose on the same stream it received the request.
I expected to see io.EOF getting called but instead it looks there was no error at all...
What could be the reason?

Client:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:8080",
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    defer conn.Close()
    c := v3.NewAccessLogServiceClient(conn)

    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("could not connect: %v", err)
        }
        var opts []grpc.CallOption
        if client, e := c.StreamAccessLogs(context.Background(), opts...); e != nil {
            log.Printf("Error: %s", e)
        } else {
            msg := v3.StreamAccessLogsMessage{
                LogEntries: &v3.StreamAccessLogsMessage_HttpLogs{
                    HttpLogs: &v3.StreamAccessLogsMessage_HTTPAccessLogEntries{
                        LogEntry: []*v31.HTTPAccessLogEntry{{
                           .....
                        }}}}}
            err2 := client.SendMsg(&msg)
            if err2 != nil {
                log.Fatalf("error calling StreamAccessLog: %v", err2)
            }
        }
        time.Sleep(7 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Server:

```
type AccessLogService struct {
}

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    go func() {
        log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil))
    }()
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    als := AccessLogService{}
    v3.RegisterAccessLogServiceServer(s, &als)
    log.Printf("Server started")
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}

func (svc *AccessLogService) StreamAccessLogs(stream v3.AccessLogService_StreamAccessLogsServer) error {
    var nodeID string
    for {
        msg, err := stream.Recv()
        log.Printf("Incoming request")
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error: %s", err.Error())
            return nil
        }

        switch entries := msg.LogEntries.(type) {
        case *v3.StreamAccessLogsMessage_HttpLogs:
            for _, entry := range entries.HttpLogs.LogEntry {
                log.Printf("A new Entry arrived")
            }
        }

        // Close the stream
        stream.SendAndClose(&v3.StreamAccessLogsResponse{})
    }
}
```

When I look at the server log, I don't see any error being called:

```
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=157 len=8
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":method" = "POST"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":scheme" = "http"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":path" = "/proto2.envoy.AccessLogService/StreamAccessLogs"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":authority" = "localhost:8080"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field "user-agent" = "grpc-go/1.54.0"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field "te" = "trailers"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read DATA stream=157 len=11 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x12\x04\n\x02\n\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=11
2023/05/16 02:43:17 Got a request
2023/05/16 02:43:17 A new Entry arrived
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=157 len=2
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote DATA stream=157 len=5 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=5
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:17 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=159 len=8
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":method" = "POST"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":scheme" = "http"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":path" = "/proto2.envoy.AccessLogService/StreamAccessLogs"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":authority" = "localhost:8080"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field "user-agent" = "grpc-go/1.54.0"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field "te" = "trailers"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read DATA stream=159 len=11 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x12\x04\n\x02\n\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=11
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 Got a request
2023/05/16 02:43:24 A new Entry arrived
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=159 len=2
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote DATA stream=159 len=5 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=5
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:24 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=161 len=8
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":method" = "POST"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":scheme" = "http"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":path" = "/proto2.envoy.AccessLogService/StreamAccessLogs"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":authority" = "localhost:8080"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field "user-agent" = "grpc-go/1.54.0"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field "te" = "trailers"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read DATA stream=161 len=11 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x12\x04\n\x02\n\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=11
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 Got a request
2023/05/16 02:43:31 A new Entry arrived
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=161 len=2
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote DATA stream=161 len=5 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=5
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:31 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=163 len=8
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":method" = "POST"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":scheme" = "http"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":path" = "/proto2.envoy.AccessLogService/StreamAccessLogs"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":authority" = "localhost:8080"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field "user-agent" = "grpc-go/1.54.0"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field "te" = "trailers"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read DATA stream=163 len=11 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x12\x04\n\x02\n\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=11
2023/05/16 02:43:38 Got a request
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 A new Entry arrived
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=163 len=2
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote DATA stream=163 len=5 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=5
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:38 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=165 len=8
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":method" = "POST"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":scheme" = "http"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":path" = "/proto2.envoy.AccessLogService/StreamAccessLogs"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":authority" = "localhost:8080"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field "user-agent" = "grpc-go/1.54.0"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field "te" = "trailers"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read DATA stream=165 len=11 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x12\x04\n\x02\n\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=11
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 Got a request
2023/05/16 02:43:45 A new Entry arrived
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=165 len=2
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote DATA stream=165 len=5 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=5
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: read PING len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
2023/05/16 02:43:45 http2: Framer 0xc0006be2a0: wrote PING flags=ACK len=8 ping="\x02\x04\x10\x10\t\x0e\a\a"
```

Any idea what I've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your client code never receives from the stream.  It sends (without checking error) and then throws away `client` when it goes to the next loop iteration.  The client needs to receive to get the status of the RPC.
2. Your server method handler never exits.  `SendAndClose` actually doesn't do anything to "close", rather it only `Send`s and is named that way to indicate that the stream shouldn't be used any longer, and that multiple `Send` operations are not valid, since it is a client-side streaming RPC.  Subsequent `Recv` operations on the stream would either receive what the client sent *or* block until a message is received from the client or the context is canceled.

The only way for a server to send a status and end the RPC is by returning from the method handler.  Once `SendAndClose` is called, you should also `return` from the method handler ASAP.

The typical pattern for a client-streaming RPC is:

1. The server receives from the stream in a loop until the client does a `CloseSend` (i.e. `Recv` returns `io.EOF`).
2. The server finishes processing the request messages from the client and responds with the response message and status code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Doug, that is much helpful.
Basically the client code is not something I can manage. I mainly try to keep my server safe from memory leak that might happened due to idle streams.
so for that I've added an idle mechanism in the server that check for idle streams every amount of time.
Perhaps do you have an elegant solution you can advise? Is it possible to cancel the context of the stream?

Comment: I would probably do something like this then: receive from the stream in a goroutine, push the received message to a channel, and have the method handler select on that message and your idleness timer.  If the timer expires, return from the method handler, which terminates the RPC.

Comment: Thanks Doug, for that solution I would have to maintain another goroutine for each stream for the idleness timer, and since my server handles many calls it would reflect on the server performnce

Comment: Typically you'll always use a separate goroutine for reading from streaming RPCs.  I wouldn't be too concerned about the performance impact of this.  If you are concerned, you could always benchmark it.

Comment: My main focus is to reduce goroutines to reduce memory. Today we maintain many streams, each one occupies a goroutine waiting on Recv and part of them are idle streams.

I use a seperate goroutine for reading the stream like you mentioned, but using a select for reading from the channel of pushed messages would enforce me to maintain another goroutine. see https://go.dev/play/p/rhzNHsJ1WDJ

so this will enforce me to maintain two goroutines for each stream, no?

Comment: The original solution that use for, so it occupies 1 goroutine:
https://go.dev/play/p/yx-UtKMwVhz

Comment: The proposed solution using select with push to channel:
https://go.dev/play/p/7lJp87gdBHi

Comment: > I use a seperate goroutine for reading the stream like you mentioned, but using a select for reading from the channel of pushed messages would enforce me to maintain another goroutine.

I don't think so.  I don't really understand how this works, though.  You have multiple streams, and all of them push their received messages onto a channel, and they also all receive off of that same channel.  Which means any stream might handle any random message recieved from any stream, including itself.  I don't understand what you could be doing with this.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I wrote a pseudo code since I cant really run this on the playground.
I updated the code here https://go.dev/play/p/cnzVYbEqt-g  
My goal is to have multiple streams and once a stream is idle I want it to be closed.
Up until now I had one goroutine occupied per open stream, now with the idle solution, my solution occupies 2 goroutines per stream. 
I hope there is a better solution than what I have written.
I appreciate your effort, Thank you.

Comment: Typically, bidirectional streams will need two running goroutines per stream: one for sending and one for receiving.  This use case is effectively bidirectional, because you want to asynchronously end the RPC.

Your other option would be to put an appropriate total timeout on every stream, and allow the client to re-establish the stream every time it is hit.

Comment: Thanks! This is practically envoy RPC so I can't really change it unfortunatelly :( It is  declared as client streaming RPC (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/api/envoy/service/accesslog/v2/als.proto#L27) 
I appreciate your help